# apache2ctl DUMP_RUN_CFG and DUMP_INCLUDES fail

Tags: apache2

I'm trying to troubleshoot Apache2 config discrepancies resulted from a recent distro and apache upgrades:

Debian wheezy -> stretch

Apache 2.2.22 -> 2.4.25

Apache2ctl tools appear to be suitable for analysis but unfortunately the 2 most useful options don't work on a clone of the old server:

```
# apache2ctl -D DUMP_RUN_CFG
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action '-D DUMP_RUN_CFG' failed.
```

same for `-D DUMP_INCLUDES`

Both commands work and return useful info on the new upgraded server.

Everything else I've tried runs fine on both the new and the old server:

```
apache2ctl -t
apache2ctl -S
apache2ctl -D DUMP_RUN_CFG
apache2ctl -D DUMP_MODULES
```

Nothing appears to be logged in Apache error.log (LogLevel debug) and syslog.

Any idea what's causing the error above and how to fix it?

Is it an Apache bug?

Comment: Just figured out that these two options were not available in 2.2 and added in 2.4.
The error message was pretty confusing!